# Error while implementing a ROS Service

Tags: ros, ros-noetic, ros-service

I am implementing a ROS Service to input two numbers but an error keeps occuring.

> File "/home/atharva/arduinobot_ws/devel/lib/testing_ros/service_client_example.py", line 15, in 
> exec(compile(fh.read(), python_script, 'exec'), context)

> File "/home/atharva/arduinobot_ws/src/testing_ros/scripts/service_client_example.py", line 17, in 
> response = exp(a,b)

> rospy.service.ServiceException: service [/Exponent] responded with an error: b'error processing request: not all arguments converted during string formatting'

Why does this error keep happening?
I have attached code for the service and client below.

Service:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import rospy
import math
from testing_ros.srv import ExponentNum, ExponentNumResponse

def ExponentNumber(req):
    rospy.loginfo("Enter two number to calculate exponent", req.a, req.b)
    return ExponentNumResponse(math.pow(req.a,req.b))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node("ExponentService", anonymous = True)
    exp_service = rospy.Service("Exponent", ExponentNum, ExponentNumber)
    rospy.loginfo("The service is up and running")
    rospy.spin()
```

Client:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import rospy
import sys
from testing_ros.srv import ExponentNum

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) == 3:
        a = int(sys.argv[1])
        b = int(sys.argv[2])
    else:
        print("Wrong number of inputs")
        sys.exit(-1)
        
    print("Requesting value of exponent ", a,b)
    rospy.wait_for_service("Exponent")
    exp = rospy.ServiceProxy("Exponent", ExponentNum)
    response = exp(a,b)
    print("The value of operation is ", response)
```

.srv file:

```
# Request
int64 a
int64 b
---
# Response
int64 exp
```

Comment: Please edit your post to show us your `ExponentNum.srv` file.

Answer (score 1):

The service-side is throwing an exception for the rospy.info() statement because of missing `%d`. The exception is logged on the service node side. The line should be something like:

`rospy.loginfo("Enter two number to calculate exponent %d %d", req.a, req.b)`

Also: the python3 `math.pow()` function returns a python float, not an int. It's recommended to convert the result to int if that's what you defined in the ExponentNumResponse class.

Comment: Added the .srv file code.

Comment: I changed the result to int but I still get the same error after running it in terminal.

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it works now